# Ubuntu crashes and I can't log in after installing NVIDIA driver through Additional Drivers

Tags: nvidia, login

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 32-bit on my PC with my USB Flash disk. I then installed an NVIDIA driver through **Additional Drivers**. Unfortunately, I forgot the driver's version, but I think it's nvidia-185.

And I rebooted my PC an ugly splash screen appeared, and I can't pass the login screen or log in.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this article](http://www.socialblogr.com/2010/10/how-to-install-nvidia-graphic-card-driver-on-ubuntu-10-10.html), I needed to disable nouveau before installing the driver.

Comment: Is Mr. lovinglinux :) I'm glad you fixed it.

Comment: that's great. thanks for the advice, mr.lovinglinux. i have been trying to fix it for a whole day. and it solved with a simple commands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reconfigure xorg. See [this thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=690760)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an Ubuntu live CD? If yes, then boot from the CD, start Nautilus with root privileges:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Then browse the root directory of your system partition (not the root of the live CD user), find `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and delete it.

Close the root file browser.

Reboot and check if you can login successfully.